# Apart from Azula, has there ever been a Fire Bender with Blue Fire?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

In *Avatar: The Last Airbender*, Azula is the only character whose fire is shown to be blue. Is there any other character capable of producing or seen using blue fire?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In *Avatar: The Last Airbender*, [dragons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPi-38oUtC8) are shown to be capable of producing flames of many colors, including purple/blue.

[image: dragon firebending, one blue streak]

In the comic *Smoke and Shadow*, Zuko is shown doing the same.

[image]

However, no other character has been shown producing the exact, consistent shade of blue fire that Azula did.

Comment: As I looked up the video and logged in you posted.  Good memory!  Link to the actual time You can see the multitude of colors here.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vx4iNwFV9iA&feature=youtu.be&t=1m20s

Comment: Nice link. I don't see blue in the dragon's fire but red and yellow (normal fire colors), and green and purple. I wonder if any human character has been shown to use green or purple fire or why the fire is even green or purple in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

No, there have been no other characters in the Avatar universe shown to have blue fire.

To elaborate, Azula's blue flame is due both to her heritage and to her single minded desire to be a worthy successor. One can improve one's bending, and one can be naturally gifted, but it was Azula's singled minded pursuit of perfect that caused her flames to be blue.

Related: [Why is Azula's fire blue?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10030/why-is-azulas-fire-blue)

Comment: So in all the years the Fire Nation has existed, no one ever thought, "I want to have the most powerful fire, do things with fire no one has ever done!"?

Comment: Sure there probably has, look at Ozai. The flames he used were massive and unending.

Comment: "but it was Azula's singled minded pursuit of perfect that caused her flames to be blue." Then shouldn't Ozai's flames be blue as well?

Comment: I also mentioned heritage. Azula and Zuko were the children of a line of Fire Lords and the line of a former Avatar. Zuko may have had blue flames but he was always gentle.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer states that no other human was shown producing blue fire. While true for the show, in the first issue of the *Smoke and Shadow* comic (2015), Zuko briefly uses a technique similar to "dragon firebending", which includes some blue streaks.

[image: Zuko bends fire like the dragons do]

Comment: I see that a lot of your answers have comic illustrations with high quality images. I'm curious to know if you own a lot of comics in digital form. Do you?

Comment: @Simpleton I have some (I own more paperbacks than digital, though). This one I'll admit I fetched "somewhere on the Internet", though...